# PHP Pagination not working in one of my php file

Tags: php, pagination

**Table Layout**

> Category Table:
>   `CategoryID | CategoryDetails`
>
> Subcategory Table:
>   `SCategoryID | CategoryID | SCategoryDetails`
>
> Company Table:
>   `companyID | CategoryID | SCategoryID | cname | cweb | cadd | ccity | cstate | country`

**index.php**

```
   <?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

include_once 'config.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylecom.css" type="text/css"></link>
<title>Dynamic Dependent Select Box using jQuery and PHP</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $(".country").change(function()
 {
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;

  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_subcat.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
      $(".state").html(html);
   } 
   });
  });


 $(".state").change(function()
 {
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id='+ id;

  $.ajax
  ({
   type: "POST",
   url: "get_com1.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,
   success: function(html)
   {
    $(".city").html(html);
   } 
   });
  });

});
</script>
<style>


</style>
</head>

<body>
<center>
<div>
<label>Category :</label> 
<select name="country" class="country">
<option selected="selected">--Select Category--</option>
<?php
 $stmt = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM category");
 $stmt->execute();
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['CategoryID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['CategoryDetails']; ?></option>
        <?php
 } 
?>
</select>

<label>SubCategory :</label> <select name="state" class="state">
<option selected="selected">--Select SubCategory--</option>
</select>


<!---<label>Company :</label> 
<select id="form" name="city" class="city">
<option selected="selected">--Select Company--</option>
</select>----->


<br />
</div>
</center>
<table name="city" class="city">
</body>
</html>
```

**get_subcat.php**

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
include('config.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
 $id=$_POST['id'];

 $stmt = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE CategoryID=:id");
 $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
 ?><option selected="selected">Select Subcategory :</option><?php
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['SCategoryID'
            . '']; ?>"><?php echo $row['SCategoryDetails']; ?></option>
        <?php
 }
}
?>
```

**get_com.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
      <head>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylecom.css" type="text/css">
      </head>
      <body>
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

include('config.php');
if($_POST['id'])
{
 $id=$_POST['id'];

 $stmt = $dbo->prepare("SELECT * FROM company WHERE SCategoryID=:id");
 $stmt->execute(array(':id' => $id));
 ?>
<option selected="selected">Select Company :</option>
 <?php
 while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
 {
  ?>
  <!---<option value=</option>--->

  <table class="city"><tr>
  <td><?php echo $row['cname'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['cweb'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['ccity'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['cstate'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['czip'];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['ccountry'];?></td>


      </tr></table>


  <?php
 }
}
?>




      </body>

  </html>
```

**`index.php`**  & other php file working fine.

I just make changes all of my code and want to paginate the table in get_com.php
how the project is working
when I click category, the subcategory dropdown populate and related company table will come.I want to paginate this table

Thanks

If anybody can help?

Comment: I recommend you look at parameterized queries (google it), the code samples you posted are vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `echo "<a href='catsample.php?page=" . ($i + 1) . "'>" `? Because to get the second page you pass 3 in the parameter and then the script calculate the offset using `$start_from = ($page - 1) * $num_rec_per_page;` (**$page - 1**)

Comment: thanks for.But pagination is still not working.Page is coming like that              :::cname ccity
Ridge Instruments Co. Decatur
ERC Inc. Huntsville

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 >|
cname ccity
Ridge Instruments Co. Decatur

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 >|

Comment: You have unnecessary semi-colons. `};`

Comment: @gautambose And what about the `if (isset($_GET['id'])) {` condition (On **catsample.php**)? When you populating the links, I don't see you also adding an `id` parameter, you only including a `page` parameter so the condition is always **false** since `id` is not set

Comment: I just changes all of my code. I want to paginate the table